# Meteor-iOS client (DDP) will not connect with Meteor 1.2 server

Tags: ios, meteor

I have a problem with a Meteor 1.2 webapp, and an "empty" Xcode project (iOS9 and swift 2.0) where we have added the meteor-ios pod by @martijnwalraven.  The Meteor iOS client has worked great for us on another Meteor 1.1 server, but we are unable to connect with our site built in Meteor 1.2. All we do is install the pod, import framework, add 
let Meteor = METDDPClient(serverURL: NSURL(string: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/websocket")!) and Meteor.connect() in AppDelegate.

The issue we are facing is described in the [Github project](https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios/issues/67) and I was wondering if anyone on SO might have something to add in terms of a workaround (we can't downgrade).

(An odd artefact also described by another person @sferoze [(post)](https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios/issues/67) with the same issue is that it sometimes works.  When we first deployed we were able to connect with the server, just like with Meteor 1.1, but then a few hours later it stopped working.)

I have pasted in the Xcode console output below.

```
2015-10-26 18:58:43.002 XXXTest[287:19025] Connecting to DDP server at URL: http://XXX.XXX.XXX/websocket
2015-10-26 18:58:43.555 XXXTest[287:18974] Connected to DDP server with protocol version: 1, sessionID: jNWpiMnLstiAy7oeS
2015-10-26 18:58:43.608 XXXTest[287:18974] Will retry opening connection after 0.100000 seconds
2015-10-26 18:58:43.710 XXXTest[287:19004] Connecting to DDP server at URL: http://XXX.XXX.XXX/websocket
2015-10-26 18:58:43.923 XXXTest[287:18974] Connected to DDP server with protocol version: 1, sessionID: f5FXA3TrKXuJjSwD2
2015-10-26 18:58:43.967 XXXTest[287:18974] Will retry opening connection after 0.100000 seconds
2015-10-26 18:58:44.069 XXXTest[287:19003] Connecting to DDP server at URL: http://XXX.XXX.XXX/websocket
2015-10-26 18:58:44.437 XXXTest[287:18974] Connected to DDP server with protocol version: 1, sessionID: X2puPy7n9vTu8yv4z
```

...etc

I thought this might be a SSL issue with iOS 9, and added NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = YES but the problem remains.

Any help with resolving this would be great !

Comment: Perhaps your proxy server (nginx) can't upgrade the connection.